# How to recover lost noScript icon for v2.3.6 for Firefox v11.0

Tags: firefox, gui, noscript

Recently, I lost the noScript icon from the toolbar area of Firefox and cannot figure out how to recover it.

If I go to a site with some java is disabled, I see an added yellow section above search bar at bottom of window with an "Options" popup along the right edge of this line, but once I enable all the java sites on a page, the "Options" line goes away and I cannot see the menu to turn them off or enable scripts globally anymore.   This used to be available via an icon up in the toolbar area which gave a popup menu to turn off sites etc.

How can I get the icon back again in the tool bar?  I cannot find any configuration item to control its visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://noscript.net/faq#qa3_2). Alternatively go to the NoScript Preferences in the Firefox menu (see [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Customizing%20Firefox%20with%20add-ons#w_what-types-of-add-ons-can-i-install) and then "To view which add-ons you have installed:", then Addons and NoScript), and enable icons from there